# Sink Faucet Cartridge Replacement

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink

Desperate for help identifying / replacing the cartridge pictured below. The faucet is old and we would like to keep it. We’ve talked to several plumbers and tried several big box and specialty shops, but no luck. Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: Why are you replacing it? Can't you just unscrew the washer and install a new one?

Comment: please add the measured dimensions to your post ... the images are unclear and the area of interest fills less than 5% of the image

Comment: Haven’t been able to find a washer that fits. 

Measurements are 1 inch in top left image and 11/16 in bottom left image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem earlier this year.  These units are widely available online.

You must measure your dead one very carefully.  There are four or five available sizes, which only differ by small amounts.  Read the quoted measurements of the online offerings as carefully as you measure.

The correct size replacement will just screw in with ease.

Don't bother trying to replace the washer, as some have suggested.  The inner mechanism is most likely siezed and a new washer will solve nothing.  I speak from experience here too.

Comment: This is very helpful. And agree about the washer. Looking back at the plumber notes, the problem is the mechanism itself. There is not a washer to replace. 

Do you have any suggestions on where to look for a replacement? 

And any brands to look for?

Comment: And to add to my message above, I think the problem the plumbers had was finding a cartridge that is the same size. So I’m worried I’ll have the same problem. 

I saw inside the left faucet “Artistic Spain,” but not seeing anything about that online.

Comment: I found a handful of suppliers on Amazon.   They were all similarly priced, about a fiver.